# SCNNode appears more/less warped depending on position (SceneKit)

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a SceneKit scene in which the camera looks down at a single sphere that rolls around atop a flat plane.

The camera has the default configuration, and is positioned at `SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, 100.0)`.

The sphere starts out in the center of the screen. At this point, the sphere looks normal, as seen in this screenshot.
[image]

But the farther away from the center it moves, the more warped/stretched it appears. As seen in this screenshot, the sphere appears warped (it looks like an egg) when it's near the edge of the screen.
[image]

The sphere is configured like this:

```
let ballNode = SCNNode()
let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: MainData.screenWidth*0.005)
let targetMaterial = SCNMaterial()

targetMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
sphereGeometry.materials = [targetMaterial]
sphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = targetMaterial
ballNode.geometry = sphereGeometry
ballNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .phong
ballNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0,0.0,20.0)
        
ballNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape.init(node: ballNode))
ballNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.dynamicObjects
ballNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.staticObjects
ballNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.nothing
ballNode.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = true
ballNode.physicsBody?.allowsResting = false
        
scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)
```

The "plane" is actually just an `SCNBox` node, and is configured like this:

```
let platform = SCNNode()
let platformGeometry = SCNBox(width: MainData.screenWidth, height: MainData.screenHeight, length: 2.0, chamferRadius: 0.0)

platform.geometry = platformGeometry

 platform.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape.init(node: platform))
platform.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.staticObjects
platform.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.dynamicObjects
platform.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.nothing
platform.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
platform.physicsBody?.allowsResting = true

scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(platform)
```

**Question: Why does the sphere appear warped (like an egg) the farther it travels from the center of the scene/screen?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why, but adding the following solved the problem:

```
cameraNode.camera?.fieldOfView = 20.0
```